# Joining tables, counting, and group to return a Model

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

So I've got a SQL query I'd like to duplicate in rails:

```
select g.* 
from gamebox_favorites f 
inner join gameboxes g on f.gamebox_id = g.id 
group by f.gamebox_id 
order by count(f.gamebox_id) desc;
```

I've been reading over the rails Active Record Query Interface site, but can't quite seem to put this together. I'd like the query to return a collection of Gamebox records, sorted by the number of 'favorites' a gamebox has. What is the cleanest way to do this in rails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this will work (works on a similarly structured database locally), though I'm not sure I have the proper models in the proper spots for what you're trying to do, so you might need to move a coule things around:

```
Gamebox.joins(:gamebox_favorites).
  group('"gamebox_favorites"."gamebox_id"').
  order('count("gamebox_favorites"."gamebox_id")')
```

On the console, this **should** compile to (in the case of PostgreSQL on the back end):

```
SELECT "gameboxes".* FROM "gamebox_favorites" 
  INNER JOIN "gamebox_favorites" 
  ON "gamebox_favorites"."gamebox_id" = "gamebox"."id" 
  GROUP BY "gamebox_favorites"."gamebox_id" 
  ORDER BY count("gamebox_favorites"."gamebox_id")
```

...and I'm guessing that you don't want do just wrap it in a `find_by_sql` call, such as:

```
Gamebox.find_by_sql("select g.* from gamebox_favorites f 
  inner join gameboxes g 
  on f.gamebox_id = g.id 
  group by f.gamebox_id 
  order by count(f.gamebox_id) desc")
```

Comment: And several databases will promptly complain that you have non-grouped and non-aggregated columns in your SELECT. PostgreSQL versions before (AFAIK) 9.2 in particular will make that complaint. MySQL and SQLite would let the ambiguity slide.

Comment: Thanks Normalocity - I'll give the above a shot. Is it typically bad practice to wrap statements in find_by_sql calls? I'd imagine it would make things slightly less database-independent. I'm not quite sure what database I'll end up using when I deploy - MySQL most likely.

Comment: @normalocity - Thanks! The above works perfectly. A quick follow-up: if I wanted to select only those GameFavorites created within a month of the current date, what is the best practice? I can't seem to find, despite length Googling, the SQL commands to do this in SQLite or Rails. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheSciz - I wouldn't say it's bad practice to wrap things in `find_by_sql`. It's provided, in part, for situations when writing a complex query in Active Record Query would make it less readable. It's true that you lose some database agnosticism with some queries, but if you have tests that cover the queries in question, then those tests will fail if/when you swap to another database, so you'll know right away (before you deploy) that something is wrong. Besides, be honest, how often do you really swap out databases? This just isn't a problem that most people face in practicality.

Comment: @TheSciz - it doesn't so much matter what database you ultimately choose for deployment. If it's MySQL, then setup a local MySQL database on your machine for development that mirrors your production environment as much as possible, and you won't have to worry about the differences between, say, MySQL queries, and SQLite queries, because you'll be using MySQL in both production and development.

Comment: @TheSciz - for your question about limiting (and I presume counting) only favorites that were created within the last month, I think you might have to jump to using a sub-query. That is, run a query for all `GameboxFavorites` created in the last month (this is the sub-query), and then run the above query where the only favorites counted are from that sub-set.

Comment: @TheSciz - Another alternative, if you're going to use this count a lot, is to use a counter cache column on the `Gamebox` model. This would make the query faster, and much easier to read, at the cost of adding a `recent_favorite_count` column to your `Gamebox` model, which stores the count of recently created favorites of that `Gamebox`, as well as some additional code to make sure the value in this column is automatically updated. Details on using a counter cache column are outlined in this RailsCasts episode on the topic: http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column